# Django: View is not being accessed during edition of the table

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I am trying to edit my entries in a table using Django. The necessary code is given below:

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url, include

from updatedb import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
                          url(r'^submit', views.submit, name='submit'),
                          url(r'^edit', views.edit, name='edit'),
                          url(r'^editdb', views.editdb, name='editdb'),
)
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from updatedb.models import Data
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

def index(request):
        return render(request, 'updatedb/data.html')

def submit(request):
        first = request.POST["first"]
        second = request.POST["second"]
        d = Data()
        d.first = first
        d.second = second
        print first
        print second
        d.save()

        if request.POST.get("submit"):
                qset = Data.objects.all()
                return render(request, 'updatedb/results.html', {'queryset':qset})

@csrf_exempt
def edit(request):
        qset = Data.objects.all()
        return render(request, 'updatedb/edit.html', {'queryset':qset})

@csrf_exempt
def editdb(request):
        print "hi"
        print request.POST.get["data"]
        return render(request, 'updatedb/editdb.html')
```

**edit.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">

    function clickable(ele)
    {
            var value = prompt("Enter the details");
            if(value)
            {
                    ele.innerHTML = value;
                    var xmlhttp;
                    $.ajax({
                            url : 'editdb',
                            type: "POST",
                            data: {data: value},
                            success: function(data){
                                if(!data)
                                    alert("Data:"+data);
                            },
                            error: function(){
                                alert("Error in the request");
                            }

                            });
                    //$.post("editdb.html", {data: value});

            }
    }
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <table>
                <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Phone Number</th>
                </tr>
                {% for record in queryset  %}
                <tr>
                        <td onClick="clickable(this)"> {{record.first}} </td>
                        <td onClick="clickable(this)"> {{record.second}}</td>
                </tr>
                {%endfor%}
        </table>

    </body>
</html>
```

Ideally on editing the values in the table, the **editdb** view should be called but that is not happening.

The error alert saying, **Error in the request** is being generated.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Your ajax call doesn't seems proper as your not checking the response in success method. And you are trying to render a template using your editdb view function which should be i think a json object.

Comment: @TanveerAlam What I ultimately want to do in my view **editdb** is to edit the data in the database depending on the changes made on the edit page. Since I've just started I have not made the complete view.

Also, what do I need to check in the success function?

Comment: show response (chrome (right click on page) -"inspect element" -> Network -> then perform ajax call)

Comment: Shouldn't your url property in $.ajax be `url: "{% url 'editdb' %}"`?

Comment: @danielcorreia On doing that I get `Reverse for 'editdb' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found`. What do I do? Total newbie. Sorry.

Comment: @PrakharMohanSrivastava seems someone beat me to answer that, check the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your URLs are mal-formed. The `edit` URL will always also match against `editdb`, so the other one will never be reached. Make sure you terminate them:

```
url(r'^submit$', views.submit, name='submit'),
url(r'^edit$', views.edit, name='edit'),
url(r'^editdb$', views.editdb, name='editdb'),
```

Comment: Can you tell me more about mal-formed URLs please? As in what to do and what not to do?